# How to install matcaffe and pycaffe on Ubuntu 17?

Tags: matlab, caffe, ubuntu-17.04

Hi I recently updated to Ubuntu 17 and the offical caffe website states that one just has to execute :

> sudo apt install caffe-cuda

This runs without any errors on my system, but how can I build caffe with matlab and python integration?

Answer (score 0):

Try using python3 in terminal as: 
$ python3 -q

> > import caffe

it should work for pycaffe. I am not so sure about matcaffe.

Comment: On ubuntu 17.10, after `sudo apt install caffe-cpu`, from python3 command line, `import caffe` returns No module named 'six'.  `apt install python3-six` didn't resolve it.